# Drupal 7 Field API: how to programmatically send AJAX request specified in #ajax property of form element?

Tags: javascript, ajax, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7 field API to reload part of my form through AJAX. I have a button which makes the call but I would like to remove it and make the call programmatically as a response to a specific event. Here is my code for the AJAX button:

```
$form['documents']['reload_document_list_button'] = array(
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => 'Обновить список документов',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'reload_document_list',
    'wrapper' => 'document-list',
    'method' => 'replace',
  ),
);
```

(See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax for details.) Is there a way to do this?

P.S. I know I can style the button to make it invisible and trigger 'click' event, but I am looking for a neater way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this, I think:

First, the `#ajax` property as you might have read accepts an `event` key. For the button element by default, this event is `mousedown`. (You can check it [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/function/ajax_pre_render_element/7)) You can change it to a custom event, say `customEvent` and trigger this custom event from your Javascript code as `jQuery('#button-id').trigger('customEvent');`.

Alternatively, you can chuck the `#ajax` property itself. Set up an AJAX endpoint (using `hook_menu`) and set `reload_document_list` as its callback. Add custom Javascript to make the request and handle the response. You can take a look at the way Drupal sends the AJAX request when you use `#ajax` from `misc/ajax.js` and use that as a reference if you want.

Comment: Amar, thanks for your reply! For now I decided to use the first advice, but instead of creating a custom event I just trigger the `mousedown` event. As for the second advice, yes, it is possible and I know how to do it, but I want to keep as close as possible to the Drupal Form API framework, including its Javascript part, which, unfortunately, isn't documented at all. This is why I prefer the first solution.

Comment: This solved a problem I was having, so thanks! I was trying to trigger an Ajax call by triggering the click event on a button, but nothing was happening. Changing it to the mousedown worked a treat.